# using im.format and im.size for a whole directory rather than a single jpeg file

Tags: python, image, directory, python-imaging-library

I already listed all .jpg files in a certain directory and used the Image.open to find the size of the image. Is there a way with PIL to do the sam only for each individual file in that certain directory?

```
    os.chdir('randomDir')
    im=Image.open("01080_creteclifs_1680x1050.jpg")
    print(im.format, im.size)
```

Is there a similar way for the whole folder, dir or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid PIL only works on a file basis, so you'll have to code the rest yourself. Fortunately, this is easy with Python:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('randomDir'):
    for fpath in files:
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(path, fpath))
        print(im.format, im.size)
```